# How to sort an array of associative arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

My array looks like this.

```
Array ( 
     [0] => Array ( 
                 [id] => 1 
                 [language] => English 
                 ) 
     [1] => Array ( 
                 [id] => 3 
                 [language] => Japanese 
                 ) 
     [2] => Array ( 
                 [id] => 4 
                 [language] => Italian 
                 ) 
      [3] => Array ( 
                 [id] => 5 
                 [language] => Spanish 
                 ) 
       [4] => Array (
                 [id] => 6 
                 [language] => French 
                 ) 
   )
```

Now what I want to do is sort this array in terms of language. So it should become like this.

```
Array ( 
     [0] => Array ( 
                 [id] => 1 
                 [language] => English 
                 ) 
     [1] => Array ( 
                 [id] => 6 
                 [language] => French 
                 ) 
      [2] => Array ( 
                 [id] => 4 
                 [language] => Italian 
                 ) 
       [3] => Array ( 
                 [id] => 3 
                 [language] => Japanese 
                 )  
        [4] => Array ( 
                 [id] => 5 
                 [language] => Spanish 
                 ) 
      )
```

Actually I did found the PHP manual helpful. It's solved. I don't know if I'm allowed to add answer to my question. But this is how I did it. I found PHP's usort very helpful for conditions like this. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

```
function build_sorter($key){
    return function ($a, $b) use ($key) {
        return strnatcmp($a[$key], $b[$key]);
    };
}

usort($langs, build_sorter('language'));
    
foreach ($langs as $value) {
    echo '<option value="'.$value['id'].'">'.$value['language'].'</option>';
}
```

Comment: Can you share what, if anything, you've tried? SO is not a 'give me the code" kind of girl.

Comment: I am going to make a rash and foolish suggestion - Have you looked at the manual [PHP Sort Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) I know is a radical idea, but give it a try, make it your friend

Comment: Check your syntax, it doesn't look like php.

Comment: Actually I did found the PHP manual helpful. It's solved. This is how I did it. I've edited the question with the solution.

Comment: @RiggsFolly the manual did help. :)

Comment: You can't add an answer in this case because the question was closed (because it's a duplicate of an existing question), but if it were open you'd certainly be welcome to add an answer if you've found one. StackOverflow is meant as a lasting resource, so the answer you've discovered could help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the `language` column and sort the original array by that array:

```
array_multisort(array_column($array, 'language'), $array);
```